# How to use default parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, default-value, optional-parameters

In other languages I can set up the method signature like

```
cookEgg(boolean hardBoiled = true)
```

This defaults the parameter `hardboiled` to `true`, if I don't receive a parameter in the method call.

How would I achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At present, you have to overload the method:

```
void cookEgg(bool hardBoiled) { ... }
void cookEgg() { cookEgg(true); }
```

C# 4.0 will add optional arguments - you will be able to write code exactly as in your original sample, and it will work as you'd expect.

Comment: I'm looking forward to this feature tbh. Rather annoying to have to make an overloaded method to have this feature at the moment. I'm also hoping for static extension methods (extending a static class, like... System.String or something).

Comment: I must be missing something, as you can easily define extension methods for `System.String` in C# 3.0.

Answer (score 11):

Default parameters are supported in C# 4 (Visual Studio 2010).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is not what you look exactly but I think **params** argument is another answer.

```
void test(params int []arg) { }
```